# org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource in Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, firebase

I tried to sync the `gradle` and I got this problem. Can anyone help me?

```
org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-measurement-connector-impl/17.0.3/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.3-javadoc.jar'.
```

and is this problem related to why I cannot connect my app to firebase?

[image: all error that i got]

**Selvin**'s edit:

steps to reproduce: create any project android project with dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
}
```

(**for me it's compile**) `gradle 4.6` with:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

but **spams Build -> Sync log with**

```
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/16.0.5/firebase-core-16.0.5-javadoc.jar
Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-measurement-connector-impl/17.0.3/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.3-javadoc.jar
```

[image: logs]
**if you try to open both URLs they return HTTP 204(No Content)**

Question how can I stop `gradle` from spamming with those messages for every sync?

Comment: Hey guys, I got the same issue today for firebase-core:16.0.6, did you find any solution?

Comment: hehe Google fixed it on their side for https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/16.0.5/firebase-core-16.0.5-javadoc.jar ... now it return 404 ... but https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/16.0.6/firebase-core-16.0.6-javadoc.jar again returns 204

Comment: [I've created the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120560250) but if they will not resolve this permanently it will prolly appear with next version this library

Comment: what is the workaround for this? this issue is adding a lot of time in gradle sync as it repeatedly tries to resolve `firebase-core-16.0.6-javadoc.jar` & `firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.4-javadoc.jar`

Comment: After the edits by Selvin, this question ought to be re-opened.

Comment: @jk7 how can we re-open this?

Comment: @RohitKaradkar  my workaround, I back to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 and all solved.

Comment: @RohitKaradkar the info about how to get a question re-opened is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).  I believe Selvin's edit addressed the reason for closure in that he provided code to reproduce the issue and the desired result.  According to the help center it looks like we now need people with 3000+ rep to vote for the question to be re-opened.

Comment: @Clamorious Only your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Aram, not really a solution as reverting build tools means you're missing out other things that have been fixed and enhanced.

Comment: @EurigJones [It is fixed for 16.0.5 and 16.0.6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120560250#comment8) with 16.x or 17.x we will see if it is perma fix

Comment: @Clamorious Yes agreed. But it solved me to pass the gradle build hurdle. Actually once the sync is over, we can revert back to the latest gradle version. It started working fine.

Comment: and ... it's back :)

Comment: Seems like [the solution is to upgrade gradle to >= 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601501/could-not-get-resource-http-firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17-0-5-jav/54675419#answer-54667409)

Comment: I fixed it by upgrading the Gradle distribution to 5.x. Go to gradle-wrapper.properties and update :

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip

Comment: I got a error if I tried to upgrade the Gradle version

Comment: ERROR: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)

Comment: @SumitSahoo The above error is not letting me switch the gradle versions

Comment: Try upgrading gradle plugin (project level build.gradle) to 3.3.1 after upgrading the distribution. It should work.

Comment: Do you have  `maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}` in your root project gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write this in your app gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'


    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

May be it's work

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Build Gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score -4):

Open settings -> Build -> Gradle -> Android Studio -> Check (Enable emmbedded maven repository)