# FirebaseAuth.getInstance() is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I updated `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0` but I didn't changed anything in my code and now `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` is null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
```

I want to check if the user is signed in or not with
`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`

And I get these errors while Gradle sync(but it was completed successfully):
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some of your code around the error?

Comment: support your Question by code

Comment: I just want to check if the user is signed in with FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()

Comment: provide complete code for best help

Comment: Which code? I don't do anymore except the login.

Comment: `FirebaseApp` requires Play Services - else `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` returns `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not get resource 'http://...firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.5-javadoc.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601501/could-not-get-resource-http-firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17-0-5-jav)

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services" in my app build.gradle and classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' in the project build.gradle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the reason for this error. I added `tools:node="replace"` to my AndroidManifest.xml because of a dependency. As I removed it all worked fine again.

Comment: My god this actually did it. Searched everywhere and had no luck until this.

Comment: I didn't have this line. I added `tools:node="merge"` and then my issue was solved!. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. `FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context)` is always null.

Tried all instructions from google but it doesn't work.

Then I removed all nuget stuffs related to Firebase one by one.
Only `keep Xamarin.Firebase.Auth`

It works perfectly. Give it a try!

**NOTE:**

- if I add `Xamarin.Firebase.Config` again, it comes back to null. So, I guess there are something wrong with this nuget

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I check github firebase-android-sdk issues and they indicate that including firebase-auth 16.0.5 does indeed solve the issue.

U can read the complete issue info here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/129

Let me know if its works!

Comment: Now I use com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5 and I get the same error

Comment: I updated my question with some errors from gradly sync

Answer (score 0):

> I found out the reason for this error. I added tools:node="replace" to
>   my AndroidManifest.xml because of a dependency. As I removed it all
>   worked fine again.

I had the same problem and Johannes's solution worked for me. I removed tools:node="replace" from AndroidManifest.xml and also removed

implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'

from gradle, which was associated with tools:node="replace"

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="RushWay"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:node="replace">
    <activity android:name=".Home">
        <intent-filter> ................................
```