# Could not get resource firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.5-javadoc.jar

Tags: java, firebase

I was trying to built my android application, but build failed because of this error:

```
org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-measurement-connector-impl/17.0.5/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.5-javadoc.jar'.
```

Any support to fix this will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed it by upgrading the Gradle distribution to `5.x`. Go to `gradle-wrapper.properties` and update:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip
```

This question might be a duplicate of:
[Could not get resource 'http://...firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.5-javadoc.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601501/could-not-get-resource-http-firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17-0-5-jav)